# Django 2.0.1: Looping to create radio buttons breaks "required" setting

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have struggled with this problem for a while so I appreciate any help, however vague.

Django 2.0.1: The "required" setting that Django uses for validating whether a field is valid works fine if I input:
`{{ client_primary_sector }}` in to the applicable html file with the "required" setting chosen via the data model (`blank=False`) or via forms.py (`attrs={"required": "required"}`). However, the "required" setting fails when I use for loops to produce radio buttons.

**See below for a working and broken example.**

**models.py:**.

```
class SurveyInstance(models.Model):
    client_primary_sector = models.CharField(choices=PRIMARY_SECTOR, null=True, default='no_selection', blank=False, max_length=100)
```

Please note from above the `default='no_selection', which is not in the PRIMARY_SECTOR choices and isn't rendered as an option to the user. This forces the user to select before data is saved (I have confirmed it works).

**forms.py**

```
class ClientProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SurveyInstance
        fields = ('client_primary_sector',)

        widgets = {'client_primary_sector': forms.RadioSelect(choices=PRIMARY_SECTOR, attrs={"required": "required"}),
              }
```

**views.py**

```
def client_profile_edit(request, pk):

    # get the record details from the database using the primary key
    survey_inst = get_object_or_404(SurveyInstance, pk=pk)

    # if details submitted by user
    if request.method == "POST":

        # get information from the posted form
        form = ClientProfileForm(request.POST, instance=survey_inst)

        if form.is_valid():
            survey_inst = form.save()

            # redirect to Next view:
            return redirect('questionnaire:business-process-management', pk=survey_inst.pk)

    else:
        # Retrieve existing data
        form = ClientProfileForm(instance=survey_inst)

    return render(request, 'questionnaire/client_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

**client_profile.html**

```
  <!-- this works: -->
  <!-- <div class="radio_3_cols">
      {{ form.client_primary_sector }}
  </div> -->

  <!-- this doesn't: -->
  {% for choice in form.client_primary_sector %}
      <div class="radio radio-primary radio-inline">
          {{ choice.tag }}
          <label for='{{ form.client_primary_sector .auto_id }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}'>{{ choice.choice_label }}</label>
      </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

You may wonder why I don't just use the working solution... I would like to be able to use the for loop logic for other situations and so require a solution.

Comment: Note you can use `choice.id_for_label` to output the full label ID.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Have you ever had the problem described in this post? In general, do for loops in conjunction with form validation work for you? I am trying to determine whether its (probably) me or something more fundamental in Django.

Comment: Well actually I'm not really sure what you're asking. What validation is not succeeding? Since you're passing an already-populated instance, one of those radio buttons will already be selected, so I'm not sure what is failing.

Comment: Thanks. i see what you mean. I have amended the post to reflect your feedback. The model is pre-populated with an arbitrary value but the radio buttons do not have this as a choice, meaning that the radio buttons appear empty to the user. This means the user has to select a radio choice, otherwise Django flags this to the user. This works when using {{ form.client_primary_sector }} but not in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question. From the documentation for 2.0:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect

The correct syntax is:

```
{% for radio in form.client_profile %}
    <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
        {{ radio.choice_label }}
        <span class="radio">{{ radio.tag }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Not whatever I found before. Confirmed as working. Hoorah!

Comment: I am facing a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64862877/13823230). Shall be glad for a solution on this.